# How to get GMT date from Unix epoch time milliseconds?

Tags: java, unix, datetime

I trying convert unix milliseconds to gmt date, I need only hours and minutes, but results are incorrect according to online converters.

What I need

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    long time = 1438050023;
   // TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time / 1000);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss dd MM yyyy");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(calendar.getTimeZone());

    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```

Result:

```
03:23:58 01 01 1970
```

Comment: In Java, times are in milli-seconds, not seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `calendar.setTimeInMillis(time / 1000)` to `calendar.setTimeInMillis(time * 1000)`

The number of milliseconds is 1000 times the number of seconds; not 1/1000 the number.

Comment: ooh gosh, what a stupid mistake, how I can not see., thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static String ConvertMillistoDatetime(long millis) {
    long second = (millis / 1000) % 60;
    long minute = (millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
    long hour = (millis / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
}
```

Try this you can keep seconds optional here